# How to validate string against regular expression string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array with the following regular expression strings.

```
var fieldTypes = [
{
    '/^[0-9]+$/',
    '/^(true|false)$/i',
    '/^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$/',
    '/^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}$/i',
    'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm',
];
```

Now how can I test whether a string matches one of them?

I'm trying something like this.

```
var value = 'some string';
if (!value.test(fieldTypes[0])) {
    alert('The value is not in the correct format.');
    return;
}
```

But this produces an error that `test()` is not a function. Obviously, it can't be called on a string directly. But how do I get a valid regular expression object from a string?

**UPDATE:**

The suggested answer is *completely* different. Please read the question before closing it. I have strings. They are coming from another source. It cannot be changed. I quite clearly asked how I can get a valid regular expression from a string. If there's no way, then that's the answer. But telling me to use a regular expression literal is not an answer.

Comment: You can do it [like **this js demo** at tio.run](https://tio.run/##ZU5BDoIwELzzij2YAJGCIAeVwM0fcFNMGroIpljSItEob8cKGA9uNpPMzs5kLrSjKpdV05JuMwwdlVBUyFn6aFBBDAcDwDsdVmSbLReeMzKrlTd8FZQrtBdeNR2P7Bn2RGMw4/f7T0hH3M1Pk/2hh9Q1YSwty11da28WGcanTkf5DXUT0w/WIfEDvaaWfi3dQsg9zUtL4hnvECfw1JG5uCrB0eXiPAkOmHFigjMSt0XVWmO0bUdGb0fD8AY) Notice that it's `regex.test(value)` and not vice versa, further in the array remove the single quotes and additional backslashes to use the items as regex patterns.

Comment: @bobblebubble: Thanks! I'm not sure I completely understand that. (I'm primarily a C/C# programmer.) Where does the `regex` come from in the `forEach()`? It looks like it's just my string, so how is it different from what I was doing?

Comment: It's just a [JS forEach loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?retiredLocale=de). Works like `array.forEach(element => { /* do something */  });`

Comment: @bobblebubble: Oh, I see now. They aren't strings, they are regular expression literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't modify the array, you likely need **to parse the strings** and generate [regex objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?retiredLocale=de).

For parsing purposes use some simple pattern like: [`^(?:\/(.*)\/([a-z]*)|.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/sxeRoa/3)

It contains two [options](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html): The left side of the alternation `\/(.*)\/([a-z]*)` will [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the pattern part into the *first group* and any flags like `i` to a *second group*. The right side `.*` matches anything else if no delimiters were found (if left side failed). Finally  construct the regexes using [`new RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?retiredLocale=de).

Further notice that the order is [`regex.test(value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) and *not* vice versa (easily confused with [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)).

```js
var fieldTypes = [
  '/^[0-9]+$/',
  '/^(true|false)$/i',   
  '/^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$/',
  '/^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}$/i',
  'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm'
];

var value = '2000-01-01';

// parse string to regex
function strToRegex(s)
{
  let m = s.match(/^(?:\/(.*)\/([a-z]*)|.*)$/);
  if(m[1])
    return new RegExp(m[1], m[2]); // delimiters
  return new RegExp(m[0]); // no delimiters
}

// test value against regex
fieldTypes.forEach(regex_str =>
{
  let regex = strToRegex(regex_str);
  console.log(regex, '=>', regex.test(value));
});
```